# Check if a time in a timezone is elapsed in php?

Tags: php, timezone

Here's the time entered by a user
**CDT 2011-02-01 16:30:00**

How do i know that if that time was passed already in php?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$usertime = strtotime('CDT 2011-02-01 16:30:00');
if (time() > $usertime) echo 'time passed';
```

Comment: perhaps you mixed up javascript and php :)

Comment: Thanks but it fails for $usertime = strtotime('IST 2011-03-04 13:30:00'); Its 3:30 PM Here

Comment: Where are you getting the time string from, Javascript? If so you're better off asking for a timestamp in Javascript which would be easier to compare against