# How do i know if a time is elapsed/expired in php?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, timestamp

Here's the scenario

I would like to know if a date like **'2011-03-04'** and time like **'17:06:00'** in a specific TimeZones like **'IST/PDT/CDT'** is elapsed by using php?

Is there any function available to check this

```
 $strDate = '2011-03-04 17:06:00';
 $TZ      = 'IST';

 $strDate = '2011-02-01 11:16:30';
 $TZ      = 'CDT';

 $strDate = '2010-08-04 07:20:00';
 $TZ      = 'IST';

 $strDate = '2011-02-27 09:55:00';
 $TZ      = 'PST';
```

I've tried/searched all over the net but no joy, please help

Yeah i tried it using **DateTime** but it doesnt work for me.. My server is in **IST** TimeZone

```
$date = new DateTime('2011-03-04 17:06:00');
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("PST"));
$newtime = $date->getTimestamp();
$time     = time();
if ($time > $usertime) 
    echo 'time passed';
else
    echo 'time NOT passed';
```

Thanks to tobyS but it too falied

```
$elapsedTime = new DateTime(
    '2011-03-04 17:00:00', // I set it to 5PM. Now the time is 5:45 PM here in INDIA
    new DateTimeZone( 'IST' )
);

$elapsedInt = $elapsedTime->diff( new DateTime() );
echo ( $elapsedInt->invert ? 'Future' : 'Past' ) . "\n";
```

Comment: Did you try [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)?

Comment: You must specify the time zone during construction of the DateTime object. Otherwise, it will be created in your servers time zone and the setTimeZone() call will re-calculate the existing time to be shifted into the foreign time zone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a time in a timezone is elapsed in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192065/check-if-a-time-in-a-timezone-is-elapsed-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object from your time data and use its [diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method against the current time.

Example code:

```
<?php

$elapsedTime = new DateTime(
    '2010-08-04 07:20:00',
    new DateTimeZone( 'IST' )
);

$notElapsedTime = new DateTime(
    '2012-08-04 07:20:00',
    new DateTimeZone( 'IST' )
);

$elapsedInt = $elapsedTime->diff( new DateTime() );

echo ( $elapsedInt->invert ? 'Future' : 'Past' ) . "\n";

$notElapsedInt = $notElapsedTime->diff( new DateTime() );

echo ( $notElapsedInt->invert ? 'Future' : 'Past' ) . "\n";

?>
```

Comment: @tobyS Thank you, Could you check for this $elapsedTime = new DateTime('2011-03-04 17:20:00', new DateTimeZone( 'IST' )); It returns 'Future' not 'Past'

Comment: Hmm, IST is interpreted as +0200. Is that the correct offset? IST is not listed as a valid time zone name on http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php. Maybe you can switch to a supported name?

Comment: The time you speficied is converted here to "Fri, 04 Mar 2011 17:20:00 +0200", which is converted to "Fri, 04 Mar 2011 16:20:00 +0100" when I switch to "Europe/Berlin".

Comment: Its there and is called 'Asia/Calcutta'

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't understand those timezones:

```
$timezone = 'America/New_York';
$date = new DateTime($strDate, new DateTimeZone($timezone));
```